# Getting 500 Internal Server Error status when executing the GET ID via RestAssured class whereas received 200 status when tried on Swagger tool

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

[Swagger - screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPNbX.jpg) [Swagger - screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIS7d.jpg)I'm practicing how to perform GET ID request in RestAssured on sample working API.
When I run the GET request on swagger tool manually I am receiving the expected api response with status code as 200 but when I tried through RestAssured scripts (in BDD format) it throw status code as 500  continuously.
Posting my scripts and error shown in the console below. Please help me to find out the issue.
**Note: I can able to successfully run RestAssured for one of the POST service for record creation.**

```
package RestfulApiDemo;
    
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
    import io.restassured.response.Response;
    import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;
    import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
    
    public class GetRecord {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            RestAssured
                .given()
                    .log().all()
                    .baseUri("http://localhost:8080/app/")
                    .basePath("videogames/{videoGameId}")
                    .pathParam("videoGameId",1)
                    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                    .get()
                .then()
                    .log().all()
                    .statusCode(200);
            
        }
    
    }
```

**Error seen in console**

```
Request method:GET
Request URI:    http://localhost:8080/app/videogames/1/
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    videoGameId=1
Headers:        Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 08 Oct 2021 19:26:08 GMT
Connection: close

<Map>
  <timestamp>1633721168226</timestamp>
  <status>500</status>
  <error>Internal Server Error</error>
  <message>Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null</message>
  <trace>java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.defineClass" is null
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:125)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:402)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.&lt;init&gt;(TransducedAccessor.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.&lt;init&gt;(AttributeProperty.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:514)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.&lt;init&gt;(JAXBContextImpl.java:331)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.&lt;init&gt;(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getStoredJaxbContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:312)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:163)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:662)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:584)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
</trace>
  <path>/app/videogames/1/</path>
</Map>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> but was <500>.

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:493)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:674)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:126)
    at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:134)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:89)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.super$2$statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1268)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:144)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy:142)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseImpl.groovy)
    at RestfulApiDemo.GetRecord.main(GetRecord.java:38)
```

Comment: Is your response `json` or `xml` format?

Comment: It's json format.

Comment: If postman works then RA could work too. Can you try the simple one `RestAssured.get("http://localhost:8080/app/videogames/1").then().log().all().statusCode(200);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Received the same error with above scripts too.

Comment: Please update the setting postman that worked for you. I will base on this to build RA request.

Comment: I'm Sorry. I typed a wrong question to you. When I say checking the API response manually it means checking the Get ID details on Swagger tools.
I have checked on Postman and throwing 500 internal error but on Swagger I am receiving the details for the ID.
I will correct the description above. Sorry again.

Comment: So please take a creenshot that swagger run successfully. I want to know how request setting in swagger look like.

Comment: Added the screenshots of swagger. Please check the screenshots in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the part `.accept(ContentType.JSON)`

```
RestAssured
        .given()
        .log().all()
        .baseUri("http://localhost:8080/app/")
        .basePath("videogames/{videoGameId}")
        .pathParam("videoGameId", 1)
        .accept(ContentType.JSON)
        .when()
        .get()
        .then()
        .log().all()
        .statusCode(200);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used .contentType(ContentType.JSON) part in the scripts. You can confirm it from above code mentioned in the description.
Moreover, I tried running the script with .accept(ContentType.JSON) but received the same error.

Comment: `.contentType(ContentType.JSON)` means request body in json format, in this case, it's not necessary because it's GET request, having no body.`.accept(ContentType.JSON)` means "I only accept json, please give me response in json format". Can you double check this issue by running cURL command in your image? And one more note: Always save the changes before sending the request in any tools.

Comment: It is working now. After adding .accept(ContentType.JSON) to the script, I'm able to get the valid ID details and status code is seen as 200. 
Thank you so much for all the help :)